# Comparing two columns in two different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all apologies for if the syntax and framing of question isn't up to the standards.

I have a MySql database .I have a table answer which contains idquestion, userAnswer, userEmailAddress as columns.

Another table multi_choice_pool, which contains idQuestion, answer_all.

Every answer.userEmailAddress has multiple entries of idQuestion and userAnswer.

I want to obtain userEmailAddress in answer table where id and answer of that userEmailAddress equals the iq and answer of multi_choice_pool.

I wrote this:

```
Select answer.userEmailAddress from answer 
where (answer.idQuestion=multi_choice_pool.idQuestion) AND  
(answer.userAnswer=multi_choice_pool.answer_all);
```

Which is giving me an error: "Unknown column 'multi_choice_pool' in where clause.

Is the syntax wrong? Or the query is wrong itself? Or my approach isn't right? Can you rectify and provide suggestion?

Comment: It is a good convention to separate object ames with '_' , and not using combinations of small and big letters.

Comment: To use the table: "multi_choice_pool", it must be included in your "select", that is, "select answer.userEmailAddress from answer, multi_choice_pool where ....."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select answer.userEmailAddress 
from answer left join multi_choice_pool
on answer.idQuestion = multi_choice_pool.idQuestion 
and answer.userAnswer = multi_choice_pool.answer_all;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't need the `WHERE` clause.

But you need the `JOIN` one :

```
SELECT answ.userEmailAddress 
FROM answer answ
LEFT OUTER JOIN multi_choice_pool mcp 
    ON answ.idQuestion = mcp.idQuestion
    AND answ.userAnswer = mcp.answer_all
```

Here is the [MySQL documentation for JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Comment: It's giving me an error: 'Unknown column'answer.userEmailAddress' in field list'. Can I even access in this way 'TableName.ColumnName'? Because the column exists.

Comment: answ.userEmailAddress